# The information is not stored in the database. Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-models

There is code in models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
b_info = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def save(self, *arg, **kwarg):
    r = requests.get(f'https://system-one.uno/api/cli/bln_check/?card={self.name[:6]}')
    if r.status_code == 200:
        _r = r.json()
        self.b_info = _r.get('reason')
```

in it, part of the number is separated and sent to the checker(connected via API), which sends information to this number. And this information is stored in the same database table as the product number.

when adding a new line to the database through the admin panel, this line is not saved in the database table. Why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried without admin panel...??

Comment: also you are not overriding the save model.

Answer (score 1):

The `save` you are defining is overriding the `models.Model.save`, that means when ever you call `Product.save()` it just executes the codes you defined.

To fix this problem you just need to add `super().save()` somewhere in your defined function:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    b_info = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        r = requests.get(f'https://system-one.uno/api/cli/bln_check/?card={self.name[:6]}')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            _r = r.json()
            self.b_info = _r.get('reason')
        super().save() # This calls models.Model.save() and will save the model
```

Also you should check if your data is validated and suitable for saving by calling `full_clean()`.

Comment: Thanks, you can provide python code. I don't know English well, so by example, it will be easier for me to understand